# Mysql, select - how to get a list of the last login

Tags: mysql, select

if I have a log of user logins

user varchar(50),

logindatetime datetime

what would the SELECT be for a list of latest login for all users

I am not sure how to mix the DISTINCT user with max(logindatetime)
I should know this but I'm having a brain hemorrhage.

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT MAX(logindatetime),user FROM t GROUP BY user`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `GROUP BY` expression wich will display 1 row per group of row with the same user, then calculate the last login time, and sort DESC.

```
Select USER
     , max(logindatetime) as LAST_LOGIN_TIME
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY LAST_LOGIN_TIME DESC
```

Comment: ORDER BY is superfluous here.